# How do you easily center an image to a DIV?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, templates

```
<div style="width:200px;height:200px;overflow:hidden;">
    <img src=".." this is a 300x500 image. > 
</div>
```

How can you make this so that it results in a 200x200 image (DIV covers the rest of the image), but the image is centered?

What's the easiest way to do this? Some JQuery plugin? What would you do?

Edit: I'd like it aligned **vertically and horizontally**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easier solution: Set the image as the `background-image` on the `<div>` instead (position = `50% 50%`) :)

This *can* be [achieved](http://jsfiddle.net/jensgram/btYma/) via jQuery (not implying this to be a good approach, though—just saying):

```
var $div = $('div'),
    $img = $('img', $div),
    src = $img.attr('src');

$div.css('background', 'url(' + src + ') no-repeat 50% 50%');
$img.remove();
```

Answer (score 2):

this should work ,give a try

```
div.img{
text-align:center
}
```

Comment: I think you meant `div img` - no img class.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work:

You calculate the difference in width between the container and the image, and offset it by that amount / 2 left by using a negative `margin-left`. I.e. `(300px - 200px) / 2 = 50px`

```
<div style="width:200px;height:200px;overflow:hidden;">
    <img src="test.png" style="margin-left:-50px">
</div>
```

Comment: @marting , this will definetly work  but we should get the height and width of the image  also right??

Comment: @martin onemorething  its not good to give negative margin on image as it may not work properly on ie , give a padding-left on the div that should take care,

Comment: @gov Do you mean that the image width can be dynamic, i.e. we need to do the offset calculation runtime?

Comment: If IE plays up, I would place the image in an extra holder `<div>` that has the width/height of the image, and offset that `margin-left` negative.

Comment: For dynamic you need to use jQuery or something similar 1) wait for the `load` event of the image. 2) measure the image and adjust the offset then.

Comment: @marting  , padding-left will take care right???it will center the image...with your logic

Comment: I suspect padding will only push your image to the right, never move it left. There's nothing wrong with negative margins per se on IE. It works fine - my only concern is in relation to inline elements (such as img). If you *really* don't want it, you could make the parent element `position:relative` and then offset the image with `display:block;position:absolute` and set `left:-50px;top:0`.

Comment: See my answer for a JS variation of this method, also at http://jsfiddle.net/steve/Ljgm8/. Uses any size div, any size img, any browser, no containers, no negative margins.

Answer (score 2):

If you use text align center , the text will also align to  center . to avoid this place image in div/span set width of div/span and use margin :0 auto;

```
 <div style="width:50px; margin: 0 auto;"> <img src="test.png"></div>
```

remember your image must be also same size of div i.e 50 px in this case or set image width to 50px.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a pure JS solution: http://jsfiddle.net/steve/Ljgm8/ for any size div, any size image, any browser, no containers, no additional libraries.

(Bonus in Firefox - the `opacity` style lets you see that the underlying child element is correctly centered.)